# On page load show dynamically added fields in ionic

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have designed job portal app using ionic and angularjs. In which I have a page name skills.html. Which code is as following

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-nav-title>
    <span>Skills</span>
  </ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>

    <div class="row responsive-sm" ng-repeat="item in inputs">
       <div class="col col-center">            
            <div class="list list-inset">
              <span class="input-label">Skill:</span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Skills" id="skill" name="skill" ng-model="skills[$index]">
            </div>  

           <div class="list list-inset">
              <span class="input-label">Proficiency:</span>
               <select ng-model="proficiency[$index]">
                    <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>  
                    <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>  
                    <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>              
              </select> 
            </div>             

       </div>
     </div>  
     <div class="row responsive-sm">
       <div class="col">
         <div class="list list-inset">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive"  ng-click="submit_skill_details()">Submit</button>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col col-50">
         <button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="addskills()">Add Skills</button>
         </div>
         <div class="col col-50">
         <button class="button button-block button-royal" ng-click="deleteskills()">Delete Skills</button>
         </div>
       </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Submittion of skills is working fine for me.I am able to show submitted skills on login to . I have to click on the "add skills" button to show the submitted skill but I want to show it on page load. For example: if user have submitted only one skill like html then on pageload it should show one row with input fields contains html . if user submit html with proficiency Beginner and click on the add skill button to add next skill css with proficiency and when user re-login and go to the skills page it should show two rows. one row for html and next one for css.

Comment: create plunker for that

Comment: how to create plunker?

Comment: Upload your code here ,http://codepen.io/ . Take a sample like http://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/Lbryzz

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div>
                <label>Drop Down</label>
                 <select id = "prof" ng-model="newPayment.prof">
                <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>  
                <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>  
                <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>              
          </select> 
            </div>
```

Data is like is :
  $scope.payments = [{
    id: 1,
    prof:'Beginner'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    prof:'Beginner'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    prof:'Intermediate'
  }];

When I click on any existing skill the data is already filled in the  drop down and visible.